# Better to loop on a function or call the function with a loop? why?

Tags: javascript

I'll do an example to let you know what I mean.

```
function test(){
    for(var i; i<100; i++)
    //Mycodehere
    //Some other code
```

OR:

```
function test(i)
//Mycodehere
```

And the function call will be like

```
function(){
    for(var i;i<100;i++)
       test(i);
}
```

Comment: "cycle", and it depends on circumstance.

Comment: I just wanted to know when is better use one more than the other. I ment loop.

Comment: Depends. I'd almost always prefer to make it it's own function. Can you give more information? Like, what exactly are you doing? Will you need to use that same bit of iteration code elsewhere?

Comment: Like, if I'm doing an algorithm and the function must "try" 10 numbers. is better doing a for and loop at the start of the function or not?

Comment: The more beef there is to the inner logic, the more reason to put it in a separate function. In the example of trial arguments, you should certainly keep the loop away from the core function. Don't put a loop, which has nothing to do with the core algorithm, in the same function as the algorithm's implementation.

Comment: As stated, it depends on what you are implementing there. The answer is about clean code rather than something catholic in code/syntax. If you find yourself doing a lot inside that for loop, then you should move that code in a separate function with a descriptive name and descriptive variables. Even the little `i` variable you put there has a different meaning when you write 2 lines or 100 lines of code into that for loop. You simply can't follow the name `i` in a 100 lines for loop body, thus you need to refactor it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always better to divide your code and keep them in functions. Doing this is a good practice as it is relatively easy to understand and reuse things after. 
The difference can be felt in major products where number of code lines are much more, so documentation and code quality helps the other person understand relatively faster.

Comment: and if I do this in another function? like `function run(){ for(var i;i<100;i++)test(i)}` obviously in run function there will be more than that

Comment: Putting the loop in the function will do the work and if the number of lines for the function gets increased then we can divide this into more funtions.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, it's six of one, half-dozen of the other. As long as your code is modular, it really comes down to personal preference.

That being said, I would personally keep the loop outside of the function. This way, the code is still readable, but doesn't hide any implementation details of the code.

Compare:

```
int ducks[];
for (int i=0; i < NUM_DUCKS; i++) {
  feed(duck[i]);
}
```

To:

```
int ducks[];
feed_ducks(ducks);
```

While both versions are perfectly readable to anybody who knows how to code, the second one hides all of the implementation details, while the first one doesn't. While it's often good to leave out details, if somebody is going to edit the code in the future, it'll be must easier if all of the details present.

Hope this helps.